# how to recover from createWriteStream error and continue to pipe?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream, pipe

when using busboy to handle file upload in node.js

```
        var uploadStream = fs.createWriteStream(imagePath);


        uploadStream.on('error', function(err) {

            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // unknown dir
                mkdirp(imageDir, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error('mkdirp error in upload')
                    } else {
                        // how to continue pipe from here?
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        file.on('data', function(data) {

            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
        });
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
        });

        // save uploaded file
        file.pipe(uploadStream);
```

if createWriteStream with an unexist dir,then an error event is fired, and I tried to handle this error by create that dir and continue the upload pipe, but I dont know how to continue the upload I tried something like

```
         uploadStream.on('error', function(err) {
            if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                // unknown dir
                mkdirp(imageDir, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error('mkdirp error in upload')
                    } else {
                        file.pipe(uploadStream) // not work
                        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(imagePath)) // only get a part of uploaded image
                    }
                })
            }
            // uploadStream.end();
        });
```

please help!!!